# DDA device out of resource(Error 12) in Hyper-V VM

Tags: hyper-v, passthrough, gpu

We're 'borrowing' a server from an IDC that had two Tesla V100 on it.

It runs Windows Server 2016.

Since it has some impressive graphics capabilities, we were looking for ways to run graphic accelerated programs(CAD, Blender, etc).
But the server doesn't have monitors connected to it, so apps can't get accelerated.

So I installed Hyper-V and enabled DDA to passthrough GPU. But it shows error 12(Out of resources) in device manager.

What can I do to use GPU passthrough?
Are there alternative ways to use accelerated graphics without physical access to the server?

We're stuck with Server 2016 for now(it's borrowed, so we really can't change that. If linux distros are the only option, let me know)